# Ember js warning with three.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

What is the correct way to use `Ember js` with `three.js`. I have tried using it with cdn by editing the index.html file which works fine but i get warning in ember-cli about `THREE` not being defined. Also installing it with bower and using `app.import` gave me similar warnings.

The app works all fine but i wanted to know what is the best way to import in this case `three.js` into an ember application without the warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a JSHint warning because it isn't aware of the global `THREE` variable you're trying to access. You have two ways to fix it:

1. Put a [`globals` directive](http://jshint.com/docs/) at the top of the file that uses the variable.
2. Setup [.jshintrc](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#using-global-variables-or-external-scripts)'s `predef`.

Hope this helps!